# django how to create and use form from existing model

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to learn Django, and I am reading this link right now:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/

If you scroll down in the link provided, it says that there are two main steps involved in validating a form and that the first step is 'validating the form' which leads to this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

It says that the first step in every validation is to use the to_python() method on a field. I don't understand what they mean when they say

"It coerces the value to correct datatype and raises ValidationError if that is not  possible. This method accepts the raw value from the widget and returns the converted value."

So suppose I have a model like this

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I created a form like so

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

now, how exactly do I use to_python() method? Do I use it in a view? Or do I have to use it in the forms.py file? If I use it in a view, what would the function be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does validates and deserializes fields input automatically.

Example view when posting form:

```
def my_view(request):
   form = UserForm() 
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): # here to_python() is run for each field
            form.save()
            # redirect

   return render_to_response('home.html', { 'form': form })
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So if the form is not valid, how would I output the error messages on the screen? Using run_validators() and then printing ValidationError? Or is there a way to do that with just the is_valid() method?

Comment: If the form is invalid it will populate itself with error messages when rendering form. Please refer to the official tutorial in django docs to see example of that. Django has the most comprehensive docs you will ever get.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the `to_python()` unless you are creating a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning). If you are going to use the ModelForm to create simple forms, you can use the clean methods.

If you want to validate only one field, you can do this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if len(username) > 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please shorten your username")

        # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
        # not.
        return username
```

if you want to clean multiple fields, you can do this:

```
class Userform(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        first_name = cleaned_data.get("first_name") 

        if len(username) > 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please shorten your username")

        if len(first_name) < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("First name is too short")

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```